# describing a curve by arc length and tangent vs. arc length and curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

As a begginer in this field, I do understand how to describe curves in the plane in terms of arc length and curvature. This is described in almost every text book dealing with curves. However, it would seem to me that a description in term of arc length, $s$, and tangent unit vector at each location $s$ along the curve would also be interesting. But I seem unable to find any discussion of it. The concept of curvature always dominates the discussion. Sure, I must be missing some basic considerations about usefulness and practicality of the various possible descriptions. Thanks for any suggestion on how to better approach the subject.

Comment: Your question is rather confusing, since the curvature is defined from the unit tangent vector. The two are closely intertwined. It is practically impossible to talk about one without talking about the other. Curvature requires the unit tangent vector for its definition. And you cannot develop the unit tangent vector very far without curvature popping out.

Comment: What I meant can perhaps be more simply described with the example of a car driving along a winding road. At each value of the travelled distance (from START) the steering wheel position corresponds (univocally, through some function) to the angle of the tangent line at that point, regardless of speed. Sure, that would univocally corresponds also to a certain radius of curvature. I was just wondering why the arc length / curvature description appears by far the preferred one.